# polygonal graph's face boundary

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading Richard J. Trudeau's book "[Introduction to Graph Theory](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Graph-Theory-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486678709)",
after defining *polygonal*

> Definition 24. A graph is *polygonal* is it is planar, connected, and
>   has the property that every edge borders on two different faces.

from page 115 it defines "bridge" then talks about polygonal graph's boundary

> Definition. A bridge in a graph is an edge whose removal would
>   increase the number of components.
>
> In a planar graph a bridge necessarily borders on only one face, and
>   an edge bordering on only one face is necessarily a bridge. Thus
>   bridges are the things that prevent planar connected graphs from being
>   polygonal. Use this fact to prove that if a planar and connected graph
>   G has the property that the boundary of every face is a cyclic graph,
>   then G is polygonal. Then show that the converse statement is false by
>   **finding a polygonal graph having a face whose boundary is not a cyclic**
>   **graph**.

I'm a bit suspicious here: "a polygonal graph having a face whose boundary is not a cyclic graph" -- is this possible?

Pls enlighten me.

Comment: What is the boundary defined as?

Comment: I had exactly the same question :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if a vertex were trying as hard as it could to be a bridge?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The external face's boundary is not a cycle graph because the central vertex is repeated.  We can make this difficulty far more evident...

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thx.... how math is fascinating as a reminder to my lack of imagination...